# read xml in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am having issues with accessing the last node in this xml document the document follows the format of

```
   <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<Created>2016-11-29T14:40:38Z</Created>
<Version>14.00</Version>
</DocumentProperties>
<OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<RemovePersonalInformation/>
</OfficeDocumentSettings>
<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<WindowHeight>8748</WindowHeight>
<WindowWidth>19428</WindowWidth>
<WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
<WindowTopY>108</WindowTopY>
<ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
<ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
</ExcelWorkbook>
<Styles>
<Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
<Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
<Borders/>
<Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
<Interior/>
<NumberFormat/>
<Protection/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s62">
<NumberFormat ss:Format="Short Date"/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s63">
<NumberFormat ss:Format="Fixed"/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s64">
<NumberFormat ss:Format="0"/>
</Style>
</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="xml File">
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="7" ss:ExpandedRowCount="771" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.55">
<Column ss:Width="57"/>
<Column ss:Width="56.4" ss:Span="1"/>
<Column ss:Index="4" ss:Width="50.4" ss:Span="3"/>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">ULSP</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">ULSD</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">ULSP</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">ULSD</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">ULSP</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">ULSD</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
```

I have tried using the following and have had problems. reading the lastnode element simply returns nearly all of the xml document

string id = "2003-06-16T00:00:00.000"; // id to be selected

```
    XElement Contact = (from xml2 in doc.Descendants("cell")
                        where xml2.Element("data").Value == id
                        select xml2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is the data type of cell and of "id"?  They probably don't match.  It is not a good idea to use Value property.  It is better to use following : (int)xml2.Element("data")

Comment: You also need a namespace so try following : XElement root = doc.Root;
XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();
XElement Contact = (from xml2 in doc.Descendants(ns + "cell")
                        where (int)xml2.Element(ns + "data") == id
                        select xml2).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score -2):

Through Bad Idea But Split Will Work Like A Charm Here ...

```
//data is your xml data in plain text format without modification
String sp1 = data.Split(new string[] { "<Created>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
String sp2 = sp1.Split(new string[] { "</Created>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
//sp2 is the required string you want which has value 2003-06-16T00:00:00.000
```

Hope This Helps ! Cheers!!

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for your help in answering my query, the XML file is a list of fuel data and can be viewed at the following link if you wouldnt mind taking the time, The data I wish to extract is the latest fuel data as the xml contains all the fuel data since 2003. Thanks for taking your time

Comment: lel bro dont call me Sir :v

Comment: lel say me thanks after i solve ur problem, anyways So you mean there are multiple created tags ?

Comment: can you send me link of whole xml file ?

Comment: trying to post the link https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/685574/XML.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166367/discussion-between-jonny-d-and-agent-orange).